# Why by default all fields in mongoose are not required?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

It seems that the default value of the required attributes of each field in mongoose schema is false. So, if I save any documents, those not required fields are not written into DB at all. I was wondering why this is designed in this way, and how I can change the default value to be true for all fields.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you update your question with your schema and a specific example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-required) `required` has nothing to do with writing into the database (especially if it is `false`). It switches the field validation on or off. Default is off.

There must be another reason why your fields are not persisted.

Comment: I actually saved a json value with different fields named like the schema defines.. This problem was solved!